# NoMethodError in Admin::Restaurants#new Active Admin Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin

I added two email fields to my Restaurant table:

```
class AddEmailsToRestaurants < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_column :restaurants, :email2, :string, null: true, default: nil
    add_column :restaurants, :email3, :string, null: true, default: nil
  end
end
```

I ran rails db:migrate and I want to add these two fields in the Active Admin form in order to create new Restaurants from the admin interface:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Restaurant do
  permit_params :email, :email2, :email3, [...]
  filter :name

  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Restaurant" do
      f.input :name
      f.input :email
      f.input :email2
      f.input :email3
      f.input :password
      f.input :password_confirmation
      f.input :address
      f.input :address2
      f.input :phone_number
      f.input :city
      f.input :post_code
      f.input :latitude
      f.input :longitude
      f.input :photo
    end
    f.actions
  end
[...]
end
```

But then when I click on 'Create new Restaurant' in my Admin interface, I get the following error: `NoMethodError in Admin::Restaurants#new` `undefined method 'email2' for #<Restaurant:0x007f9490cc0340>`

How can I solve this ?

Comment: So, a stupid question but I have to ask... did you restart your application?  Even if you're running in development (which reloads changed files) the table structure information may not have been refrehed.

Comment: Oh yes thank you I'm so stupid... That was the problem... Sorry about that.

Comment: Great. It's not stupid, it's worth noting. I'll post an answer on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that a running development environment will not detect changes to a table structure after a migration.

If you add columns via a migration, be sure to stop and restart your development server.